# O echo está imprimindo as tags HTML

Tags: php, jquery

Fiz um script pra assinatura de newsletter, o usuário envia o email para cadastro.php e de lá o script recebe um echo numa mensagem com botão, o problema é que o botão não aparece, o que aparece é a tag, vejam:

Script:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#ok").click(function()
    {
        $("#formulario_news").hide("slow");
        BeforeSend:$("#carregando_news").show("slow");
        var email = $("#email").val();
        $.post("<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/newsletter/cadastro.php",{email: email}, function(data)
        {
            complete:$("#carregando_news").hide("slow");
            $("#retorno").show("slow").text(data);
            $("#voltar").click(function()
            {
                $("#retorno").hide("slow");
                $("#formulario_news").show("slow");
            });
        });
    });
});
<div id="newsletter">

        <h1>/Assine nosso newsletter</h1>

        <div id="formulario_news">
            <span>Informe seu email:</span>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
            <input type="submit" name="ok" id="ok" class="btn_ok" value="OK"/>
        </div>

        <div id="carregando_news" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/imagens/ajax-loader.gif"/> <p> Aguarde, enviando...</p>
        </div> <!-- Carregando newsletter -->

        <div id="retorno" style="padding:10px;border:1px solid #0F0;background:#C1FFD1;width:170px;margin-left:3px;margin-bottom:3px;display:none;font:14px Trebuchet;
            font-weight:bold;">
        </div>

</div>
```

cadastro.php:

```
$email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
if(empty($email))
{
    echo "Informe seu email</br>";
    echo "<button type="button" id="voltar"/>Voltar</button>";
}
elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo "Informe um email válido</br>";
    echo "<button type="button" id="voltar"/>Voltar</button>";
}
```

Vamos supor que o usuário não informe o email e clique no botão OK. O retorno é esse:

```
Informe seu email</br>
<button type="button" id="voltar"/>Voltar</button>
```

As tags aparecem escritas, o navegador não pula linha e o botão não aparece.

Comment: Não sei se essa é a causa do problema, mas vc está usando aspas duplas para delimitar a string e usando as mesmas dentro da string: `"<button type="button" id="voltar"/>Voltar</button>"`

Comment: Eu acabei digitando errado aqui no fórum. Mas era o método text(), tem que usar o html().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
$("#retorno").show("slow").text(data);
                            ↑
```

Ao usar o método `.text()`, as tags são tratadas como texto. Utilize o método `.html()`:

```
$("#retorno").show("slow").html(data);
                            ↑
```

O método `.html()` irá inserir o valor de `data` como HTML em vez de texto.

> Conforme havia comentado, há uma quebra na string do `echo`:

```
echo "<button type="button" id="voltar"/>Voltar</button>";
```

Você está delimitando a string com aspas duplas e usando as mesmas aspas dentro da string. Troque as aspas duplas dentro da string por aspas simples:

```
echo "<button type='button' id='voltar'>Voltar</button>";
                   ↑      ↑    ↑      ↑
```

A tag `button` não necessita de um fechamento da forma que colocou:

```
echo "<button type='button' id='voltar'/>Voltar</button>";
                                       ↑
                                    errado!
```

A tag é fechada no `</button>`.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é no seu `echo` você esta utilizando aspas duplas para declarar o conteúdo do do `echo` e como na sua `tag` `html` existe aspas duplas você deve utilizar aspas simples como no exemplo abaixo ou concatenar com uma contra barra onde tiver a necessidade de utilizar a aspas duplas.

```
$email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
if(empty($email))
{
    echo 'Informe seu email</br>';
    echo '<button type="button" id="voltar"/>Voltar</button>';
}
elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo 'Informe um email válido</br>';
    echo '<button type="button" id="voltar"/>Voltar</button>';
}
```

Comment: Já passei muitas vezes por esse problema, algo simples e que dá muita dor de cabeça. Muito bem esclarecido.